# Class I bluetooth mouse

Tags: keyboard, mouse, bluetooth

I'm showing a number of affordable Class I bluetooth adapters on Amazon.  Can these be used with any bluetooth mouse, or do I need a dedicated Class I bluetooth adapter/mouse combo?

A Class II pairing would also work, but not Class III (most consumer grade wireless mice are Class III and only transmit 30 feet if that).

Comment: It really depends on the device.  In my (personal) experience most wireless mice can only communicate with the reciever that comes with it.

Comment: @Ramhound that's what I was afraid of.   Thanks.